# ^[[A in terminal when navigating to past commands

Tags: command-line, 22.04

When I run a command like "yarn build" in a terminal window and then use the up arrow after the command finishes, there is this text visible:

```
^[[A
```

What I expect to happen is to see yarn build again.
However, when I just press enter on the the text, it executes yarn just fine.

So what is that text, why I am seeing it, and is there some way to "fix" it.

Comment: Have you changed from the default bash shell? What are the outputs of `echo "$0"` and `echo "$SHELL"`?

Comment: Is this specific to that one command, or does it happen with other/all commands as well?

Comment: The output of `echo "$0"` is bash (/bin/bash). It is not happening on all commands. Yarn is where I usually notice it, so it may be specific to yarn.

Comment: Similar github issue, pointing to a possible `node` change: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/763